# Match <a> anchor tags in string, extract their `href`

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to link all  tags in a string to their respective href's so it can be tapped and opened in browser.

This is what I have,

```
<p>This is a simple text with some embedded <a href="http://example.com/link/to/some/page?param1=77&param2=22">links</a>. 
This is a <a href="https://exmp.le/sample-page/?uu=1">different link</a>.
```

How do I process this text and link all anchor tags to their respective href?

pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
let finalContentLabel = TTTAttributedLabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
for (linkText, linkHref) in paragraph.anchorTags() {
    let range:NSRange = (finalContentLabel.text as! NSString).range(of: linkText)
    finalContentLabel.addLink(to: URL(string: linkHref), with: range)
}
```

I have figured out everything but `paragraph.anchorTags()` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard label and attributed string created from HTML, then you'll have links in your label

```
let label = UILabel()
let attributedText = try? NSAttributedString(data: <your string>.data(using: .utf8)!, options: 
            [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, 
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 ], 
            documentAttributes: nil)
```

// NEXT WILL BE OBJC

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];

self.textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:self.label.bounds.size];
self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
self.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.label.numberOfLines;
self.textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.label.lineBreakMode;
self.layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
[self.layoutManager addTextContainer:self.textContainer];
self.textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.label.attributedText];
[self.textStorage addLayoutManager:self.layoutManager];
```

In an attributed string, ranges of text with links will have attribute `NSLinkAttributeName`. You can `enumerateAttribute` over that attribute and for each range of that attribute add your own font and color, remove that `NSLinkAttributeName` from the range, and add `MYLinkAttributeName` attribute instead.

```
[attributedText enumerateAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length) options:kNilOptions usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            if (nil != value)
            {
                [mutableText addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:greenColor range:range];
                [mutableText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:greenColor range:range];
                [mutableText addAttribute:MYLinkAttributeName value:value range:range];
                [mutableText removeAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName range:range];
            }
        }];
```

Afterwards, add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the label and implement its `delegate` callback

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    self.textContainer.size = self.label.bounds.size;
    NSUInteger index = [self.layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:[touch locationInView:self.label]
                                             inTextContainer:self.textContainer
                    fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
    self.lastTouchedLinkAttributeValue = [self.label.attributedText attribute:MYLinkAttributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:NULL];

    return nil != self.lastTouchedLinkAttributeValue;
}
```

And finally, recognizer action:

```
- (IBAction)tapRegognized:(id)sender
{
    // Here value of 'href' is stored in self.lastTouchedLinkAttributeValue as NSURL instance.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, I have already applied a font and a color attribute to the paragraph text, I am unable to apply this additional link attribute on an AttributedString. I am not sure how to apply an additional attribute to an existing attributedString.